# How can I use annotations instead of XML to create a custom component tag in embedded Tomcat

Tags: jsf, annotations, jsf-2.2, custom-component, embedded-tomcat-8

#### Edit: The only technologies required to reproduce this issue are `JSF 2.2` and `Spring Boot 1.2.1` + Its embedded `Tomcat 8.0.5` server. Everything else listed in this question is just to give context on the tech I'm using.

> Update #2: Following along with BalusC's thoughts, I ported my sample custom component into a barebones `Servlet 3.1` + `JSF 2.2` application. You can find the code for it on Github [here.](https://github.com/MeisterGit/simple-servlet)
>
> This simple case does not exhibit the issue I'm describing here. The `@FacesComponent` annotation works. This heavily implies that the problem is being caused either by `Spring 4.1.2` or `Spring Boot` itself. It's getting late, so I'll be investigating this further tomorrow.

TL;DR: I want to use `@FacesComponent` and its attributes to replace `foundation-components-html.taglib.xml` and the `<component>` entry in `faces-config.xml`

I currently have custom components working in my project using XML definitions. I recently learned that JSF 2.2 introduced a [feature](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#594) which removes the need for XML entirely. I would love to use this, but when I purely use annotations, they are ignored by JSF. Raw tags show up in my HTML.

(i.e. `<custom:paragraph></custom:paragraph>`)

I have demonstrated this issue in a sandbox of mine I keep hosted on Github. If you want to take a crack at that, I'll explain how at the bottom of this post.

All you need to do is delete `foundation-components-html.taglib.xml`, and comment out the `faces-config.xml` entry for `<component`> and run the application to encounter the issue. I left it in the 'functioning' state so that anyone who wishes to help has an easy, verifiably correct starting point. Just hit up http://localhost:8080

> Technologies Used:
>
> - Spring Boot 1.2.1
> - JSF 2.2 via Mojarra 2.2.6
> - Embedded Tomcat 8.0.5

**NOTE:** Remember, this setup currently works, but it's running on the taglib and faces-config entries! My question is how to remove these dependencies using the latest features in `JSF 2.2`

[Full Project](https://github.com/MeisterGit/FoundationServer)

[Custom Component](https://github.com/MeisterGit/FoundationServer/blob/master/src/main/java/foundation/components/UIParagraph.java)

```
package foundation.components;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;

/**
 * The Paragraph Component
 * @author Seth Ellison
 */
@FacesComponent(value=UIParagraph.COMPONENT_TYPE, createTag=true, tagName="paragraph", namespace="http://www.blah.com/components/html")
public class UIParagraph extends UIComponentBase {

public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "foundation.components.Paragraph";

private String value;
private String styleClass;

@Override
public void encodeBegin(final FacesContext facesContext) throws IOException {

    // Encode Implementation Omitted for Brevity. 
}

@Override
public String getFamily() {        
    return "blah.components.family";
}

// Getters/Setters...

}
```

[Taglib Definition](https://github.com/MeisterGit/FoundationServer/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/tags/foundation-components-html.taglib.xml)

```
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">

    <namespace>http://www.blah.com/components/html</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>paragraph</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>foundation.components.Paragraph</component-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

[Faces Config](https://github.com/MeisterGit/FoundationServer/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml)

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
        version="2.2" metadata-complete="false">

    <component>
        <component-type>foundation.components.Paragraph</component-type>
        <component-class>foundation.components.UIParagraph</component-class>
    </component>  
</faces-config>
```

[XHTML Template](https://github.com/MeisterGit/FoundationServer/blob/master/src/main/webapp/content/index.xhtml) (Stripped down for clarity)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
  xmlns:custom="http://www.blah.com/components/html">

    <head jsf:id="head"></head>
    <body jsf:id="body">
       <custom:paragraph value="This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique." />
    </body>
</html>
```

If you'd like to run this, the easiest way would be to download the Spring Tool Suite, grab the code from Github, right click the project, and run it as a Spring Boot App. You'll get a connection error when the JPA configuration fires up, because you (likely) aren't running a local MySQL server. Don't worry about this. It's not at all required to visit the index page and check out the tag status. I frequently run the app both with, and without the DB fired up to no ill effect. Lastly, to get PrettyFaces to play nice with Spring Boot, you have to create either a Symbolic Link or a Hard Link from target/classes into WEB-INF/ -- PrettyFaces is coded to look in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib when scanning for annotations.

### Snippets for BalusC

This function exists in a class which is marked with `@Configuration` and implements `ServletContextAware`

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(
            new ConfigureListener());
}
```

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You're currently implying that Spring Boot, Spring Security, PrimeFaces and PrettyFaces are crucial in order to reproduce the problem. Eliminate that noise from the question and project to make it better focused.

Comment: BalusC, I could really use your help. I only tagged the technologies required. I didn't tag anything which wasn't relevant. I have a TL;DR, I have a focused question, I have all of the relevant code shown plus a backup reference to a sandbox implementation, with instructions on how to start it up. First you tell me I didn't give you enough information (previous question), now you're upset I gave you too much? I deleted my last question because it was too general, and I didn't spend enough time on it. I put a lot of effort into this question. I've read the mcve. This was my second shot.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the essence of MCVE. The code should not only be complete, but also **minimal**. Does the problem disappear if you remove e.g. PrettyFaces? No? Keep it out! Does the problem disappear if you remove e.g. `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver`? No? Keep it out! Does the problem disappear if you remove e.g. `<div class="jumbotron">`? No? Keep it out! And so forth for all that other libs/config/code.

Comment: I added a note on what is actually relevant,  and will be editing the question.

Comment: Alright, done editing. How's that?

Comment: Okay. Now, to exclude one and other, rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. Do you see the JSF-generated HTML output, or do you still see the raw JSF source code?

Comment: Everything is HTML, except for the single custom tag, which still reads `<custom:paragraph></custom:paragraph>`

Comment: So, you're seeing `<body id="body">` instead of `<body jsf:id="body">` and the `xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"` is entirely removed?

Comment: Yes. http://imgur.com/Nl3dTVQ This is what is rendered when I view source on the page.

Comment: Okay. `FacesServlet` is correctly hit. What do you see in server startup log as to actually used JSF version printed by `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`?

Comment: JSF 2.2 I have previously printed this out at runtime, but here's the JSF-relevant portion of my startup log. http://imgur.com/pSk1df1 -- Nothing citing `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` shows up in my log.

Comment: I register a bean called jsfConfigureListener with Java like so:
    
    `@Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(
          new ConfigureListener());
    }` -- I'll put this in the question formatted.

Comment: This starts to go beyond me as I don't do Spring. When I merely copypaste the `UIParagraph` class into a completely blank playground project with everything set to Servlet 3.1 / JSF 2.2 defaults (except of FacesServlet being mapped on *.xhtml) and run on Mojarra 2.2.6 and Tomcat 8.0.14, then everything works just fine for me. I'd suspect Spring Boot although I have completely no idea what it is doing. I recommend you to retry it without Spring Boot on a normal environment so that you can compare and exclude.

Comment: Spring Boot is built on top of Servlet 3.1. Do you think I should hit up the Spring Boot devs with a reference to this comment chain, and see if any of them have an insight? As a fun little side-note, PrimeFaces works. Though I don't know if they use annotations or the taglib + faces-config style. I can make this work using the older style which requires XML, I would just really, really like to use the new style.

Comment: PrimeFaces is JSF 2.0 compatible and doesn't use JSF 2.2 specific things. As to Spring Boot, I still recommend to try without it, just to exclude other probable causes.

Comment: Alright, I can do that, but under the covers of this simplified example, I'm working inside a large Spring Boot application. I wont be able to swap it out if it's the cause.

Comment: This is not for real. This is just for test. Ya know, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Otherwise Spring Boot guys wouldn't be happy wasting time investigating when it appears to be not a Spring Boot problem after all.

Comment: Alright, do you suggest I drop down to plain old Spring 4.1.2 (the base for Spring Boot) or Servlet 3.1? It'll take me a bit of time to suss out what needs to be done for this. Spring is a monster to configure without Boot at your back, and I've never done work directly in Servlet before. We're escaping the bounds of my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what was causing the issue.

This morning I sat down to think about the differences between my working `Servlet 3.1` version of the code, and the broken `Spring Boot` version. The main difference was how the code was being run. Embedded server vs. Standalone.

> `Spring Boot`'s embedded  `Tomcat` server was the cause.

When I switched my sandbox around in accordance with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27226488/4166413), everything turned on normally, and my custom components worked purely off of the `@FacesComponent` annotation!

I figure this has something to do with the way classes are organized post-startup on the embedded server vs. a discrete deploy to the Pivotal Tomcat server. JSF's annotation scanner seems to simply ignore annotations in that case.